# Adding jokers to a deck of cards

Tags: f#, playing-cards

I originally had the following code:

```
type Suit = | Spades
            | Clubs
            | Diamonds
            | Hearts

type Face = | Two  | Three | Four  | Five
            | Six  | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten
            | Jack | Queen | King  | Ace

type Card = { Face:Face; Suit:Suit }

let suits = [Spades; Clubs; Diamonds; Hearts]
let faces = [Two; Three; Four; Five; Six; Seven; Eight; Nine; Ten;
             Jack; Queen; King; Ace]

let deck = [for suit in suits do
                for face in faces do
                    yield {Face=face; Suit=suit}]
```

The output was:

```
val deck : Card list =
  [{Face = Two;
    Suit = Spades;}; {Face = Three;
                      Suit = Spades;}; {Face = Four;
                                        Suit = Spades;}; {Face = Five;
                                                          Suit = Spades;};
   {Face = Six;
    Suit = Spades;}; {Face = Seven;
                      Suit = Spades;}; {Face = Eight;
                                        Suit = Spades;}; {Face = Nine;
                                                          Suit = Spades;};
   {Face = Ten;
    Suit = Spades;}; {Face = Jack;
                      Suit = Spades;}; {Face = Queen;
                                        Suit = Spades;}; {Face = King;
                                                          Suit = Spades;};
   {Face = Ace;
    Suit = Spades;}; {Face = Two;
                      Suit = Clubs;}; {Face = Three;
                                       Suit = Clubs;}; {Face = Four;
                                                        Suit = Clubs;};
   {Face = Five;
    Suit = Clubs;}; {Face = Six;
                     Suit = Clubs;}; {Face = Seven;
                                      Suit = Clubs;}; {Face = Eight;
                                                       Suit = Clubs;};
   {Face = Nine;
    Suit = Clubs;}; {Face = Ten;
                     Suit = Clubs;}; {Face = Jack;
                                      Suit = Clubs;}; {Face = Queen;
                                                       Suit = Clubs;};
   {Face = King;
    Suit = Clubs;}; {Face = Ace;
                     Suit = Clubs;}; {Face = Two;
                                      Suit = Diamonds;}; {Face = Three;
                                                          Suit = Diamonds;};
   {Face = Four;
    Suit = Diamonds;}; {Face = Five;
                        Suit = Diamonds;}; {Face = Six;
                                            Suit = Diamonds;};
   {Face = Seven;
    Suit = Diamonds;}; {Face = Eight;
                        Suit = Diamonds;}; {Face = Nine;
                                            Suit = Diamonds;};
   {Face = Ten;
    Suit = Diamonds;}; {Face = Jack;
                        Suit = Diamonds;}; {Face = Queen;
                                            Suit = Diamonds;};
   {Face = King;
    Suit = Diamonds;}; {Face = Ace;
                        Suit = Diamonds;}; {Face = Two;
                                            Suit = Hearts;}; {Face = Three;
                                                              Suit = Hearts;};
   {Face = Four;
    Suit = Hearts;}; {Face = Five;
                      Suit = Hearts;}; {Face = Six;
                                        Suit = Hearts;}; {Face = Seven;
                                                          Suit = Hearts;};
   {Face = Eight;
    Suit = Hearts;}; {Face = Nine;
                      Suit = Hearts;}; {Face = Ten;
                                        Suit = Hearts;}; {Face = Jack;
                                                          Suit = Hearts;};
   {Face = Queen;
    Suit = Hearts;}; {Face = King;
                      Suit = Hearts;}; {Face = Ace;
                                        Suit = Hearts;}]
```

However, the code above did not account for jokers.

So I updated the code to the following:

```
type Suit = 
    | Spades | Hearts 
    | Clubs  | Diamonds

type Face =
    | Ace  | King  | Queen | Jack | Ten
    | Nine | Eight | Seven | Six  | Five | Four | Three | Two

type Joker = BigJoker | LittleJoker

type Standard = { Face:Face; Suit:Suit }

and Card = 
    | Card of Standard 
    | Wild of Joker

let suits = [Spades; Hearts; Clubs; Diamonds]

let faces = [Ace; King; Queen; Jack; Ten; Nine; Eight; Seven
             Six; Five; Four; Three; Two]

let deck = [for suit in suits do
                for face in faces do
                    yield Card { Face=face; Suit=suit }
           ] @ [Wild BigJoker
                Wild LittleJoker]
```

The output is now:

```
val deck : Card list =
  [Card {Face = Ace;
         Suit = Spades;}; Card {Face = King;
                                Suit = Spades;}; Card {Face = Queen;
                                                       Suit = Spades;};
   Card {Face = Jack;
         Suit = Spades;}; Card {Face = Ten;
                                Suit = Spades;}; Card {Face = Nine;
                                                       Suit = Spades;};
   Card {Face = Eight;
         Suit = Spades;}; Card {Face = Seven;
                                Suit = Spades;}; Card {Face = Six;
                                                       Suit = Spades;};
   Card {Face = Five;
         Suit = Spades;}; Card {Face = Four;
                                Suit = Spades;}; Card {Face = Three;
                                                       Suit = Spades;};
   Card {Face = Two;
         Suit = Spades;}; Card {Face = Ace;
                                Suit = Hearts;}; Card {Face = King;
                                                       Suit = Hearts;};
   Card {Face = Queen;
         Suit = Hearts;}; Card {Face = Jack;
                                Suit = Hearts;}; Card {Face = Ten;
                                                       Suit = Hearts;};
   Card {Face = Nine;
         Suit = Hearts;}; Card {Face = Eight;
                                Suit = Hearts;}; Card {Face = Seven;
                                                       Suit = Hearts;};
   Card {Face = Six;
         Suit = Hearts;}; Card {Face = Five;
                                Suit = Hearts;}; Card {Face = Four;
                                                       Suit = Hearts;};
   Card {Face = Three;
         Suit = Hearts;}; Card {Face = Two;
                                Suit = Hearts;}; Card {Face = Ace;
                                                       Suit = Clubs;};
   Card {Face = King;
         Suit = Clubs;}; Card {Face = Queen;
                               Suit = Clubs;}; Card {Face = Jack;
                                                     Suit = Clubs;};
   Card {Face = Ten;
         Suit = Clubs;}; Card {Face = Nine;
                               Suit = Clubs;}; Card {Face = Eight;
                                                     Suit = Clubs;};
   Card {Face = Seven;
         Suit = Clubs;}; Card {Face = Six;
                               Suit = Clubs;}; Card {Face = Five;
                                                     Suit = Clubs;};
   Card {Face = Four;
         Suit = Clubs;}; Card {Face = Three;
                               Suit = Clubs;}; Card {Face = Two;
                                                     Suit = Clubs;};
   Card {Face = Ace;
         Suit = Diamonds;}; Card {Face = King;
                                  Suit = Diamonds;}; Card {Face = Queen;
                                                           Suit = Diamonds;};
   Card {Face = Jack;
         Suit = Diamonds;}; Card {Face = Ten;
                                  Suit = Diamonds;}; Card {Face = Nine;
                                                           Suit = Diamonds;};
   Card {Face = Eight;
         Suit = Diamonds;}; Card {Face = Seven;
                                  Suit = Diamonds;}; Card {Face = Six;
                                                           Suit = Diamonds;};
   Card {Face = Five;
         Suit = Diamonds;}; Card {Face = Four;
                                  Suit = Diamonds;}; Card {Face = Three;
                                                           Suit = Diamonds;};
   Card {Face = Two;
         Suit = Diamonds;}; Wild BigJoker; Wild LittleJoker]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what sort of feedback you're looking for since you didn't include any questions, but your deck-building can be made a little more efficient:

```
let deck = [
    for suit in suits do
        for face in faces do
            yield Card { Face=face; Suit=suit }
    yield Wild BigJoker
    yield Wild LittleJoker
]
```

The original version made two lists and used the `@` operator to concatenate them into a third list, while this version just creates a single list.

Jokers aren't always the only wild card, depending on the game you're playing. I might personally hesitate to encode into the type system that only Jokers are wild.

One other option might be...

```
and Card = 
    | Card of Standard 
    | Joker of Joker
```

...or possibly you could make Joker a suit, and BigJoker/LittleJoker face values in that suit. But then the type system wouldn't prevent you from creating the BigJoker of Spades, which would be a little weird.

Comment: Also possibly a good idea: ``and Card = | Card of Standard | LittleJoker | BigJoker`` Might flatten out the ``match c with ...`` sections later on.